# How can I remove previous result of search from listview using C# and SQL

Tags: c#

I want to remove the previous result from `ListView` because the first result is fine but the second is duplicate the result. How can I solve this problem?

```
private void btn_search(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=Student; Integrated Security=true");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM info WHERE id LIKE '" + box4.Text + "%'", con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row[0].ToString());

        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            item.SubItems.Add(row[i].ToString());
        }

        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

---

Update based on comments:

```
private void btn4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=Student; Integrated Security=true");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM info WHERE id LIKE '" + box4.Text + "%'", con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    listView1.Items.Clear();

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row[0].ToString());

        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            item.SubItems.Add(row[i].ToString());
        }

        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit question so that it invalidates existing answers. If someone answers your question then up-vote and accept their answer.

Comment: ok , thank you for your advice

Comment: My fault; I asked him to edit it to show the new code.

Comment: @PhilM - It's ok to ask for code updates, but they should always be put at the end of the existing question as a further update section.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Clear the ListView (before you repopulate with the new data):

```
ListView1.Items.Clear();
```

You could put it at the very beginning of the function (before all the SQL work). Or, if you wanted to test you got data back properly first, you could put it after the test, and before your loop.

Comment: You tried where (update your post with the new code).

Comment: how ?? can you explain for me in details ? or tell me where i can put ListView1.Items.Clear(); and i will try !!

Comment: Can you describe how the change wasn't working? Where you had it in your edit looked right.

Comment: @OthmanAli - I've put a placeholder in your question. Can you put your updated code there?

Comment: When you say it 'doesn't work', can you be more specific? Is each run appending more data to the ListView? Are you running the exact same query, getting the exact same data back, and thus nothing changes in the ListView (which would be working correctly)? Something else?

Comment: well , when i write the text that i want to search it the first result is correct but the second result is not correct because their is a duplicate for data , and why the data is saved when i was search in the second time ??

Comment: @OthmanAli - The `listView1.Items.Clear();` should have solved the problem. You will need to post a [mcve] to get further help. Please read that link and let me know if you have any problems. Also, please use the `@` notification system when replying.

Comment: @phil we can say for ex : i search for number in the database like 2 the first result give me all number which contain number 2 that is good , but when i was searched again to the number 22 as a example the output is the result for the first search + second search , say the first search is 8 rows the second result will be 1 row so the listview show the all outputs 8+1 i don't want like that , i want to each search be once , i hope you understand me

Comment: @Enigmativity this is the first time to use stackoverflow so i didn't understand how i can help you ??

Comment: @OthmanAli - I want the simplest code possible that I can copy, paste, and run to see the problem you are facing. The code you've shown doesn't replicate your problem so it's impossible to help without seeing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=Student; Integrated Security=true");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name,id FROM info WHERE id LIKE '" + txtbox1.Text + "%'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row[0].ToString());
            for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                item.SubItems.Add(row[i].ToString());
            }
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
}
```

after i update to this code it work in correct way , thanks for everyone who help me .